# How do C libraries store state variables?

Tags: c, variables, libraries

I've been developing in C for a while now, coming from object-oriented languages like C++ and Java, and whilst using standard library functions like `fread()` and `strtok()`, I began to wonder: How do these functions go about storing variables related to their state?

For example, `strtok()` behaves differently for subsequent calls, and `fread()` keeps track of your position in the file.  This information has to be stored somewhere, and in an object-oriented language there are scope constructs such as `private` or `protected` to guard these values from unwanted modification, but as far as I understand C does not have these.

So then, how are they safely stored?  Or are they in fact global and modifiable from anywhere?  The question spawned when I was writing a header file with utility functions that needed to store similar state information.  What is the "right" way to do this sort of thing in C, and how is it handled in existing libraries?

Comment: `fread` does not need to save state between calls, since it takes a `FILE` struct which stores all the information needed by `fread`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These calls use `static` variables. A local static variable retains its value between function calls. A global static variable or a function is accessible only by other functions declared in the same file.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's still possible to reach, for instance, a static global variable (file scope) from another file by passing it a pointer (the address) to the variable.

Comment: The _in the same file_ part was what I was missing.  I didn't realize access to global static variables was restricted by file. Thanks!

Comment: @sizeman Just note, as i tried to explain above, it's the *linker* that can't see it outside of the file, however if you have a file `A` with a global `static int a` you can pass the address of `a` to the file `B` and still access the variable from file `B`. I think that's important to know, even if it's not something you do every day.

Comment: @Jite, I think I understand.  But in that case, the file with the original static global would have logic in it to pass that pointer out somehow.  I was asking more from a security standpoint.  If a file you include doesn't want you to access a global, it can do so by declaring it static (as far as I understand).

Comment: A static variable need not have file scope for a pointer to it to be taken.  A pointer to a function-scoped static is equally valid.  *lifetime* and *scope* are distinct attributes.

Comment: @sizeman Not sure I understood you correctly now but I mean you declare the static variable in the `.c` file, and you usually don't include `.c` files in other `.c` files. This means that the header files you include does not even mention any static variables. The header file exposes external functions, while these functions in turn can have references to static variables in the implementation file. Example: you import say `string.h` and get `strstr()` declaration, `string.c` implements the function might use static global variables that you never see. Not sure if it got any more clear?

Comment: This answer remains correct only for strtok().  fread() uses information in the FILE object passed to it by reference.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of fread() the state is stored in a FILE structure.  The structure is a resource allocated by `fopen()` which returns a pointer to it, and you pass that pointer to every file operation call.  The resource is released when `fclose()` is called.  The FILE resource may be allocated from a static pool or it may be dynamically allocated from the heap - that would be implementation dependent. For example:

```
RESOURCE* getResource()
{
    return malloc( sizeof(RESOURCE) ) ; 
}

int useResource( RESOURCE* r )
{
   return r.index++ ;
}

void releaseResource( RESOURCE* r )
{
   free( r ) ;
}
```

`strtok()` on the other hand contains an internal static pointer that is initialised when a string is passed and used as the starting point when a null pointer is passed.

For example:

```
int getState()
{
    static int state = 0 ;
    return state++ ;
}

int main()
{
    int s ;

    do
    {
        s = getState() ;
        printf( "state = %d\n", s ;

    } while( s < 10 ) ;
}
```

Comment: Using your example to clarify something, in your second code snippet, I could not access `state` nor make a pointer to it directly from `main()` correct?

Comment: @sizeman : Correct, the getState function would have to explicitly return a pointer as in the getResource example, for it's state to be accessed externally. These are not the only possibilities, they are just the approaches used by fread and strtok.  One might return a handle or index to internally held data for example, rather than a pointer, or an opaque type.